# Comparing Java subclasses

Tags: java

My app may compare instances of any two sub-classes of the same abstract parent class. I want them compared as follows:

1. If they are different sub-classes, the parent class should do the comparison.
2. If they are the same sub-class, the sub-class should do the comparison.

The classes will be compared by a TreeMap, so I have a choice of using a Comparator, or implementing Comparable (or both?).

I can think of several ways to do this, but they are all a bit messy and error-prone. Is there an elegant solution?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean by "the classes will be compared by a Treemap"?

Comment: Since you mention Comparable and Comparator, can we assume the result of the comparison has all three possibilities - 'less than', 'greater than' and 'equal to'?
If the comparison excludes the possibility of even one of these options, then you should not be using those interfaces.

Comment: Do you mean to compare classes through reflexsion? As in what methods and properties each class has?

Comment: This is a very difficult task, because the contract of compare() imposes transitivity: if b1 > b2 (with the B subclass comparison), and if a > b1 (with the base class comparison), then you must have a > b2 (with the base class comparison). Given that the base class comparison doesn't know anything about the subclass comparison, this is very hard to achieve.

Comment: @JBNizet - while i don't think the OP's idea is necessarily a great one, i don't think maintaining that transitivity is difficult as long as your subclass ordering is always a "sub-comparison" of the superclass ordering.

Comment: @jtahlborn: agreed. But given the wording of the question, I don't think that it's what the OP plans to do. It seems like the subclass is completely responsible for the comparison if both objects are of the same subclass.

Comment: Is there a library which takes care of the comparison framework?  Ofcourse the actual comparing is application specific, but the logic of where to compare which subclass isn't (the library could check/enforce issues like transitivity and sub-comparison).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your replies. I posted my current solution as an answer. It is not perfect but I think it's as good as it will get. I'd appreciate your opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
// Parent:
@Override
public final int compareTo(Parent other)
{
  if (getClass() == other.getClasss()) {
    // same type -> pass it to subclass implementation
    return this.subCompare(other)
  }

  // different type -> do the comparison here based on Parent's logic
  // ...
}

protected int subCompare(Parent other)
{
  // this should not be called directly
  return 0; // could throw an exception here too
}

// Derived1:
@Override
protected int subCompare(Parent other)
{
  // this method is only called from Parent
  Derived1 other1 = (Derived1) other;
  // do the comparison based on Derived1's logic
}
```

Similarly for other derived classes

Comment: would probably make the parent compare() final to avoid accidental overrides.  otherwise this works as long as the decision does not need to be made at an arbitrary depth in the hierarchy.

Comment: Just fyi. "this instanceof other.getClasss()" is not a valid statement in Java...

Comment: yeah, you just want "getClass() == other.getClass()"

Comment: Thanks. This is close to what I'm already doing and probably as elegant as it's going to get. Except I'm using a hybrid solution with Comparator and Comparable: the Comparator checks if they are different sub-classes and if so handles the comparison. Otherwise, it calls subclass.compareTo().

Comment: @BarryFruitman You could improve the guarantees by first comparing according to the base class rules, and only if they are **equal**, then break the tie by going for a more specific comparison based on the subclasses.

Comment: Please see my own answer below and tell me what you think. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik perhaps by using Guava: [Ordering.compound()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#compound%28java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: @Attila: Thanks. I think we are on the same track. Our approaches are essentially the same except I'm performing the initial comparison in a Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but:
I believe that what you are doing is error prone and problematic.
The equality test imposed by the `compareTo` method should generally return the same results as the `equals` method. I.e. the ordering imposed by the `compareTo` method is *should* be consistent with `equals`.
If this contract is violated you could run into problems with sorted collection (which you are using).
Why I am saying this:
The fact that you want to delegate comparison to the parent class in certain cases indicates to me that you have added a value component in the subclass.
If you did this then there is no way possible to preserve the `equals` contract and you could run in problems with sorted container (see above)

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be error prone either way. You could do something like this in your subclass:

class Subclass1 ... {

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if(o instanceof Subclass1) {
    return super.equals(o);
  }

  ... compare subclasses
}
```

}

Comment: I need a comparison, not equality check.

Answer (score 0):

Should the class hierarchy be extendible or not?
=> If it is not extendible (or rarely will be extended) you could implement a Comperator so that all comparing code is in one place.

Is there more than one way to order the objects?
=> If so, then you 'll have to use a comperator for each order.

`compareTo(other)` (or `compare(o1, o2)`) is invoked from three situations:

1. `this instanceof other.class` (i.e. `o1 instanceof o2.class`):

   - this.class should compare `this` and `o2` since it has more information than other.class;
2. `other instanceof this.class` (i.e. `o2 instanceof o1.class`):

   - other.class should compare `other` and `this` and this.class.compareTo should flip the result and return it.
3. exist first common ancestor P such that `this instanceof P` && `other instanceof P`:

   - P should compare `this` and `other`: call super.compareTo(other) recursively and return the result.

Comment: This is one of the "messy" solutions I referred to in my question. The Comparator would have to be aware of and be able to compare any combination of sub-classes, which is impossible since instances of the same sub-class might need to compare each other using private members.

Comment: To avoid the Comperator having to be aware to all subclass combinations, the Comperator could be implemented using a similar hierarchy as the Comparable objects.  Ofcourse that doesn't help with the private access needed.

Comment: yeah, i don't think Comparator is the way to go here.  think you want to stick with Comparable impl.

Comment: Please compare Attila's solution with mine. Potato/Potahto IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm doing it now. I think this is as elegant as it's going to get:

```
public abstract class ParentClass implements Comparable<ParentClass> {
    // compareTo(ParentClass) is implicitly abstract
}


public class SubClass1 extends ParentClass /* Comparable<> is implicitly implemented */ {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ParentClass another) {
        SubClass1 subAnother = (SubClass1) another;
        return /* result of sub-class comparison */;
    }
}


public class MyComparator implements Comparator<ParentClass> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ParentClass lhs, ParentClass rhs) {

        // Are lhs and rhs instances of the same sub-class?
        if(!lhs.getClass().equals(rhs.getClass()))
            // They are different. Use parent class comparison.
            return /* result of parent class comparison */;

        // They are the same. Use sub-class comparison.
        return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
    }
}
```

Then I just pass an instance of `MyComparator` to the `TreeMap`. It handles the different-sub-class comparison, or passes the comparison to the sub-class if they're the same.

What I don't like is that `SubClass1.compareTo()` will throw a `ClassCastException` if `another` is an instance of another sub-class. However I don't have to worry about this as long as I make sure the sub-classes are only compared by `MyComparator`.

Comment: you could add a method to which only MyComperator has acces, move the current implementation of compareTo there, and in compareTo call MyComperator.compare.

Comment: @KaspervandenBerg: I prefer to keep compareTo() in the sub-classes so it can access private members.

Comment: Ok I figured out how to avoid the ClassCastException: Comparable doesn't need to be implemented since compareTo() is only ever called by MyComparator. Instead, I just made compareTo() a plain old abstract protected method in ParentClass. Now I can be 100% certain compareTo() will only be called with same-sub-class instances.

Comment: that was what I intended to say ;)