# How to sort a linked list based on one attribute withing a class with other attributes present

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have an abstract class with name and price as attribute
i have three base classes book, shoe and card, has attributes author, size and quantity respectively along with several other attributes

I have my driver class where i implemented a linked list which asks user to enter information and forms a linked list
I am trying to display three different things
1) ONLY books sorted by authors name
2) only shoes sorted by size

I have trying to implement my comparator in driver class with one overridden method for now

```
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator() 
    { 
    @Override
     public Boolean compare(double s1, double s2) 
    { return s1 < s2; } 
    } 
    )
```

the program gives unresolved compilation error
I need to understand if I have to implement comparator in all classes or just the driver and can put my three over riden methods

also what might i be doing wrong

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725007/comparing-java-subclasses

Comment: _the program gives unresolved compilation error_ Can you include the full error?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a compilation error, it will be great to see it :-)
2. You need to define the way how sorting will compare instances of all your classes.
   For this either your classes need to implement Comparable interface or you need to provide a Comparator. For natural order it's better to implement Comparable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote you can achieve what you described as follow:

```
class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Item> list = Arrays.asList(new Book("author1"),
                new Book("z-author2"),
                new Book("g-author2"),
                new Shoe(39),
                new Shoe(40),
                new Shoe(41),
                new Shoe(1),
                new Shoe(2));

        //ONLY books sorted by authors name
        List<Item> books = list.stream()
                .filter(o -> o instanceof Book)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> ((Book) o).getAuthor()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //only shoes sorted by size
        List<Item> shoes = list.stream()
                .filter(o -> o instanceof Shoe)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> ((Shoe) o).getSize()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(books);
        System.out.println(shoes);
    }
}

public abstract class Item {
    String name;
    int price;
}

class Book extends Item {
    String author;

    public Book(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "author:" + author;
    }
}

class Shoe extends Item {
    int size;

    public Shoe(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "size:" + size;
    }
}

class Card extends Item {
    int quantity;

    public Card(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

(the code is compilable)

Your question is not clear though. You could wrote some code and gave some more information about the error you are talking too.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. 
So all my classes had several attributes and i just had to compare one out of them, sort based on that and display it

-- User inputs, out of different types of object, we make other smaller linked list extracting that info

eg : shoes, card, books , shoe , card --user input 
~ then make linked list of author of type book and sort the author
display that